# Reference Error: Data is not defined when trying to pass a json object to java file

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to pass a json object to a query the show the query results. I believe everything I have done is correct but i keep getting thrown the Reference Error: data is not defined. I have tried everything and even debugging and stepping through the program is not working for me because my break points in my javascript never seem to be getting hit; same with my java.

Anyway here is my java code:

```
    @POST
    @Path("module")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<ModuleProcCount> getInput(int jobId) throws IOException{
        try (Dbc dbc = vehmPool.getDbc()){
            List<ModuleProcCount> pusher = statements.inMod(dbc, jobId);
            return pusher;
        } 

    }
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$scope.sendJobId = function(cellVal) {
    data.jobId = cellVal;
    $http.post("rest/performance/module", data.jobId).then(function(response){
        $scope.pusher = response.data;

});
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<table id="Table" class="JobID-table" style="text-align:center" >
                    <tr class="table-Header">
                        <th>JOB ID</th>
                        <th>TIME FOR ALL MODULES(MILLISECONDS)</th> 
                     </tr>
                     <tr class="jobID-Table-tr" ng-repeat="p in puller | orderBy : '-modCount'"> 

                            <td ng-click="sendJobId(p.modName)" class={{p.cellClass}}>
                                {{p.modName}}   
                            </td>

                            <td  class={{p.cellClass}}>             
                                {{p.modCount}}
                            </td>


                     </tr>

                </table>
```

Comment: you are using `data.jobId` but I can't see any where that you have declared the `var data = {}` or anything similar in `js` file

Comment: It's a **query** - not a "quarry" ......